# How do I write code to return data from "Submit" to "Filename"?

Tags: python, openpyxl, pysimplegui

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg
sg.theme("DarkTeal2")
layout = [[sg.T("")], [sg.Text("Choose a file: "), sg.Input(), sg.FileBrowse(key="-IN-")],[sg.Button("Submit")]]

###Building Window
window = sg.Window('My File Browser', layout, size=(600,150))
    
while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED or event=="Exit":
        break
    elif event == **"Submit"**:
        print(values["-IN-"])


# read
filename = r"C:\Users\filename.xlsx"
book = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename)

# sheet 
sheet = book.worksheets[0]

# read file list
data = []
for row in sheet.rows:
    data.append([
        row[0].value,
        ' ',
        row[3].value,
        row[4].value,
        row[5].value,
        row[6].value, 
        row[7].value,
        row[8].value,
 ])

data = data[1:]
```

Currently, we are writing a code to load and input an Excel file.

First of all, I implemented the GUI as in the code above, and I even wrote the Excel data.

How do I write code to return data from "Submit" to "Filename"?

Answer (score 1):

Just define a function to get a filename and return it.

```py
def get_filename():
    layout = [
        [sg.T("")],
        [sg.Text("Choose a file: "),
         sg.Input(),
         sg.FileBrowse(key="-IN-")],
        [sg.Button("Submit")],
    ]
    window = sg.Window('My File Browser', layout)

    while True:
        event, values = window.read()
        if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
            filename = ''
            break
        elif event == "Submit":
            filename = values["-IN-"]
            break
    window.close()
    return filename
```